# Exclude certain characters using RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

Try as I might, I can't get a RegEx to exclude space or single quotes.

- The string "abc" is allowed
- Not allowed: "a'bc", "'", "'abc", "'''", "abc''" etc
- Spaces could replace the ' too in the above example
- Trailing and leading spaces are assumed to be removed already
- Empty strings are checked elsewhere
- Target language is javascript

I'd use PATINDEX if I was in SQL.

Or NOT a positive match on either space or single quote, if I could negate...

I've tried (for single quote only)

- `\w*[^']\w*`
- `^\w*[^']\w*$`
- others I forget now

Please put me out of my misery so I can sleep tonight.

Edit:

- Target string will not be surrounded by Quotes. I thought thy might add clarity
- If "Target language is javascript" is wrong, then it's c#. I'd have to check where we do the validation exactly: client javascript or server c#

Comment: What regular expression language?  Python, Perl, C#, Java?  They are all subtly different.

Comment: It the test string always going to be surrounded in double quotes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
^[^\'\ ]*$
```

?

Comment: Isn't it more standard to use the \s character class for the whitespace?  (and at least in some flavors of regex, \S matches NON-whitespace...)

Answer (score 8):

Quite simple. Does not allow empty strings.

```
^[^' ]+$
```

Comment: wuub answered first but thanks +1.  This also works. Why + and not * though please?

Comment: +1 for the non escaped version. You're probably better regexper that I am :)

Comment: + instead of * to disallow empty strings.

Answer (score 2):

i think this

```
^\w*$
```

should work as `\w` does not include single quote or space.

Answer (score 1):

Without reading the details, I don't see [^ '] in there anywhere (with a space and a single-quote).

Comment: Correct. I was initially testing for single quote only