# match ascii characters except few characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regexp that matches all ascii characters:

```
/^[\x00-\x7F]*$/
```

Now I need to exclude from this range the following characters: `'`, `"`. How do I do that?

Comment: You can refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127739/exclude-certain-characters-using-regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead for disallowed chars:

```
/^((?!['"])[\x00-\x7F])*$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kR7zR0/2)

`(?!['"])` is negative lookahead to disallow single/double quotes in your input.

Comment: can you please explain elaborately how this negative lookahead works in this particular regex? I've read [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) on lookarounds but can't seem to grasp how this particular lookeahed works. Particularly I'm wondering why it's not applied only to one character. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `['"]` will match either `'` or `"`. `(?!['"])` is negative lookahead which asserts that next character position is not `'` and `"`

Comment: Next character after current input position. Read this good tutorial on this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 3):

You can exclude characters from a range by doing

```
/^(?![\.])[\x00-\x7F]*$/
```

prefixed it with `(?![\.])` to exlude `.` from the regex match.

or in your scenario

```
/^(?!['"])[\x00-\x7F]*$/
```

**Edit:**

wrap the regex in braces to match it multiple times

```
/^((?!['"])[\x00-\x7F])*$/
```

Comment: No, not this way. `^(?![\.])[\x00-\x7F]*$` matches some strings that do not start with a period. And ``\`` is redundant in the character class.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, corrected the same to match it multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

The IMO by far simplest solution:

```
/^[\x00-\x21\x23-\x26\x28-\x7F]*$/
```