# Why does lookahead check every character?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regexp

```
^((?!['"])[\x00-\x7F])*$
```

and it matches the following string

```
no its all right lag
```

I ran it through RegexBuddy debugger and it seems that the check of negative lookahed `(?!['"])` is done after every literal character match:

[image]

Is it how it works?

Comment: Why do you care if the engine checks the lookahead. Is it slowing you down?

Comment: @sln, I just want to understand the internals of the lookahead

Comment: It's no mystery. Expressions are processed left to right, so naturally ..

Comment: @dustmouse, thanks, that is how it is checked on every character

Comment: The internals of lookaheads are beyond the scope of this question. Suffice it to say, they can't be backtracked into externally and is a design factor.

Comment: Lookarounds are a value-added feature, they qualify between characters. Stuff like `(?=[a-z\d])[a-z]*\d*[a-z]*` prohibits an empty match on all optional stuff. But stuff like `(?=^)` or `(?<=^)` is meaningless as is `(?=\d)?`

Comment: @sln, thanks, but too complicated yet :)

Comment: It can get pretty complicated, for example nested assertions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does check every character that the `[\x00-\x7F]` matches.

The negative lookahead here is used to restrict the `[\x00-\x7F]` character class. The pattern can be described as *match a whole string that consists of only ASCII characters excluding `'` and `"`*. Since you applied a `*` quantifier to `((?!['"])[\x00-\x7F])` group, the regex engine tries to match this pattern zero or more times, from the start of the string to its end, thus, checking each position inside it. You could make this expression more efficient if you split the range as:

```
^[\x00-\x21\x23-\x26\x28-\x7F]*$
```

You would avoid the backtracking caused by using a lookahead (note that the `"` is `\x22` and `'` is `\x27`).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sT5kI1/1):

[image]

Comment: thanks, I know what it does and how it can be optimized, it's from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427094/match-ascii-characters-except-few-characters). I'm just trying to understand whether lookahead matches one position or many. It seems that it matches just one position but because of the repetition it matches every time, correct? And if I changed the expression to `([\x00-\x7F](?!['"]))`, that would be different I suppose?

Comment: Yes, the lookaheads checks, that is, it matches the character right after the current position in the string where the current index resides. Since the `['"]` is a single character pattern (all characters inside the character class are just "alternatives", i.e. it is an optimized `('|")` regex), it just checks one character, one at a time, up to the end of the string due to the anchors and the quantifier. Mostly due to the quantifier.

Comment: I see, thanks. Where is the picture from? If I changed the expression to ([\x00-\x7F](?!['"])), that would be different I suppose?

Comment: The screen is from [`regex101.com`](https://regex101.com/r/sT5kI1/1), *regex debugger* page (when PCRE option is used). If you use `([\x00-\x7F](?!['"]))` the pattern will only match an ASCII character that is not followed with `"` or `'`. You can use [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mO2sJ9/1) to see what various regex patterns mean.

Answer (score 3):

This regex matches 0 or more of ascii characters from `0-127` range except single quote and double quote characters.

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
(
   (?!           Negative lookahead start
      ['"]       either ' OR "
   )             Negative lookahead end
   [\x00-\x7F]   Match ascii character from 0-127
)*               Match 0 or more of preceding group
```

So yes before matching any ascii char in `0-127`, negative lookahead asserts that next character position is not single/double quote.